# [HELP]filters in the spatial domain[JAVA]

Tags: java, filter, noise

I'm doing the method for applying the arithmetic average filter to an image, according to me, is already good, but the image is very ugly, here they are my methods.

```
public static void mediaAritmetic(){
        int smallWidth = Imagen.ancho - 3 + 1;
        int smallHeight = Imagen.altura - 3 + 1;
        int [][] output = new int [smallWidth][smallHeight];
        for(int i=0;i<smallWidth;++i){
            for(int j=0;j<smallHeight;++j){
                output[i][j] = singlePixelConvolution(Imagen.getGris(),i,j, 3,3);
                Imagen.imagenTrabajada.setRGB(i, j, output[i][j]);
            }
        }
        Imagen.setImagenTrabajadaDos(Imagen.imagenTrabajada);
    }

    public static int singlePixelConvolution(int[][] input,
                                             int x, int y,
                                             int kernelWidth,
                                             int kernelHeight){
        int output = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<kernelWidth;++i){
            for(int j=0;j<kernelHeight;++j){
                output = (output + (input[x+i][y+j]));
            }
        }
        return output/kernelHeight*kernelHeight;
    }
```

where is the input image. Imagen.getGris is the matrix with the gray scale image.

PREVIEW:

[Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdZEE.png)
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGt6s.png)

Comment: `return output/kernelHeight*kernelHeight` is missing parentheses.

Comment: It doesn't calculate "something / 9", it calculates "something / 3 and that multiplied by 3".

Comment: yes, sorry, im already add this, but same result

Comment: @Tom here is the fromula [link](http://image.slidesharecdn.com/imagerestoration-141022065948-conversion-gate01/95/image-restoration-digital-image-processing-30-638.jpg?cb=1413961304)

Comment: No worries, I don't need that formula. I already know it since I have my own image editor implemented which also implements the average filter.

Comment: I appreciate a lot, I've tried a thousand ways, but does not work

Comment: One thing wonders me a bit: why don't you work with the single colors? You're using int and I guess you get that number from `Color#getRGB`, but you should extract the potions of red, green and blue and apply the average filter on each single color.

Comment: What happens is that transformed the gray scale image and put it in a two-dimensional array, and only work with gray pixels, and this arrangement is occupied for all methods.

Comment: I did with this method [Method](https://github.com/fertwo/procesamientodeimagenes/blob/master/src/ar/com/untref/imagenes/filtros/FiltroDeLaMedia.java)... and yes this works, but 
to apply the geometric mean, or harmonic filter, and would be different, I'm right?

Comment: Even when it is a gray scale image, it still does have different saturations for red, green and blue. And btw, you're doing integer addition on line `output = (output + (input[x+i][y+j]))` and that may also overflow the integer range.

Comment: I follow the example of the convolution of neighbors, in the method singlePixelConvolution, add the nearby pixels, and divided by the length of the mask, or could you give me an example of your method to guide me, as with any achievement it work.

Comment: The general algo already looks correct. What I would change is, to convert the number `input[x+i][y+j]` into an instance of `java.awt.Color` to extract the red, green and blue potions of that number, add each value individually for the neighbor matrix (maybe with divsion in the loop, not outside) and then combine the resulting three numbers into one again by using `java.awt.Color` again. Check the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html) to find suitable methods.

Comment: thanks, im try this.

Comment: Two notes: combine these number outside of the loop, when you're done calculating the average. And mind `Color` might bite you, if the passed numbers for each individual colors aren't in range of 0 and 255, so you might need to add a helper method which caps numbers higher than 255 (i.e. "if higher than 255, then use 255 instead").